# which random am i looking for to achieve this:

Tags: python, random

Trying to just generate a random amount of either `[` or `]`.

```
sample = random.choice("[]")
```

The above prints either `[` or `]`, how can I get it to print a random number of either or both of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat the procedure a random number of times:

```
[random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))]
```

will produce a list with *up to* 10 random selections of the three choices available, starting with *at least one*. Note that I used a list of the 3 *strings*, not just 2 characters here.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))]
[']', '[]']
>>> [random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))]
['[', '[]', ']', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]']
```

If you need this as one string, use `str.join()` to concatenate the results:

```
''.join([random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))])
```

Note that this'll produce a string between 1 and 20 characters long, as you concatenate a random selection of up to 10 strings each 1 or 2 characters long. Use `random.choice('[]')` if you need a string up to 10 characters long instead.

Comment: how can i get this out put to be like [][][][][] and no , and brackets in between them ?

Comment: @johndoe12345: you mean *one string* of random length, with *only* repeated `[]` characters in them?

Comment: @johndoe12345: use `''.join()` to join a sequence of strings, `''.join(['[]' for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))])` would produce such a string.

Comment: still getting invalid syntax on this --------sample = [random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))] ''.join(['[]' for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10)])


print sample

Comment: ok thanks. now its just joining [] all the time. sorry in my post above i meant i wanted the output on one line but it could be like [[[[[[[]]]]]]][][][][][][] and not just all []

Comment: @johndoe12345 then use the code in my answer. Try to understand what each part of the code does so you know how to alter it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.randint` within `range` and use a for loop to crate a random number of `[` or `]`.

```
>>> def random_printer(N):
...      for _ in range(random.randint(1,N)):
...          print (random.choice(('[', ']', '[]')))
...
```

Demo :

```
>>> random_printer(5)
[
]
>>> random_printer(10)
[]
[]
]
>>> random_printer(10)
[]
[
[
[]
[]
]
]
]
[]
```

Comment: Easy fix: `random.choice('[', ']', '[]')`.

Comment: @Kasramvd `how can i get it to print a random number of either or both of these` I am confused

Comment: how can i get this output on the one line ?

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `(1, N)` rather than `(1, N-1)`?

Comment: @johndoe12345 - You can get the output in one line by using `print(..., sep=' ')`.

Comment: print (random.choice(('[', ']', '[]')) sep =' ') - this is saying syntax error , am i missing something ?